# selector don't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 block:

```
<div class="going" filmid="2">
<a href="">I am going!</a>
<div>Going too: 20</div>
</div>
```

and 5 blocks:

```
<div class="going">
<a href="">I am going!</a>
<div>Going too: 20</div>
</div>
```

The difference in that one block have `filmid` attribute.
My js function:

```
function setUpUpdateGoingCount() {
            $("div.going a").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var filmId = $(this).parent("div").attr("filmid");
                $.post("/Cinema/UpdateGoingCount", { id: filmId }, function () {
                    alert("test");
                });
            });
        }
```

Click event work well with block without `filmid` atrribute.
Can you explain me why and how to do that first block works well?

Comment: please define "works well"... what happens on first block? what doctype are you using?

Comment: I mean that the second blocks shows messgage (test), first block only reload page.

Comment: and, UpdateGoingCount calls only for second blocks.

Comment: which jquery version are you using? and doctype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `filmid` is not an attribute that exists in HTML, you should instead use a data attribute:

```
<div class="going" data-filmid="2">
```

You can access this with:

```
var filmId = $(this).parent("div").data("filmid");
```

Answer (score 2):

AJAX post is sent either way. The anchors (links) inside divs with `filmid` set, are sent with the param `id` set to the content of filmid. The divs not containing `filmid` are sent with the param empty.

**UDATE**
If you mean by *not working* that the javascript doesn't show the alert message, that may be because you are getting an error on that call, and you'll need to specify an error function this way:

```
function setUpUpdateGoingCount() {
    $("div.going a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filmId = $(this).parent("div").attr("filmid");
        $.post("/Cinema/UpdateGoingCount", {
            id: filmId
        }, function() {
            alert("test");
        }).error(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
}
```

This is a working example with your code http://jsfiddle.net/hpgsL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a second class to the blocks without the filmid to use in your selector as the .click is going to get binded to all div .going a whether they have a filmid attribute or not.